# How to change button color after all fields are filled in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tried changing button color, after user enter all fields, but issue with the computed property,

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      terms: false,
      fullname:'',
       maxfullname: 10,
      mobile: '',
      maxmobile: 10,
      area: '',
      maxarea: 12,
      city: '',
      maxcity: 12,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
       return !this.terms || (this.fullname.length  < this.max !="") || (this.mobile.length < this.maxmobile)
   || (this.area.length < this.maxarea) || (this.city.length < this.maxcity);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.register-button {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee1d24;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.selected {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms'/> I accept terms!!!
      <input id="fullname" type='text' v-model='fullname'  :maxlength="maxfullname"/> name
      <input id="mobile" type='text' v-model='mobile'/ :maxlength="maxmobile"> mobile
       <input id="area" type='text' v-model='area' :maxlength="maxarea"/> area
      <input id="city" type='text' v-model='city':maxlength="maxcity"/> city
    </label>
    
  </p>
   
  <button class="register-button" :class="{'selected': isDisabled}" :disabled='!isDisabled'  v-on:click=" isFirstScreen">Send Form</button>
</div>
```

Tried changing button color, after user enter all fields, but issue with the computed property,
Tried changing button color, after user enter all fields, but issue with the computed property,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      terms: false,
      fullname:'',
      maxfullname: 10,
      mobile: '',
      maxmobile: 10,
      area: '',
      maxarea: 12,
      city: '',
      maxcity: 12,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
       return !this.terms 
         || this.fullname === ''
         || this.mobile === ''
         || this.area === ''
         || this.city === ''
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.register-button {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee1d24;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.selected {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms'/> I accept terms!!!
      <input id="fullname" type='text' v-model='fullname'  :maxlength="maxfullname"/> name
      <input id="mobile" type='text' v-model='mobile'/ :maxlength="maxmobile"> mobile
       <input id="area" type='text' v-model='area' :maxlength="maxarea"/> area
      <input id="city" type='text' v-model='city':maxlength="maxcity"/> city
    </label>
    
  </p>
   
  <button class="register-button" :class="(isDisabled) ? '' : 'selected'" :disabled='isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine,But  until user fill maxcharacters in each filed then only button color should change. For the above code maxlength condition is not satisfying, even if i enter single digit in each field, button color is changing

Comment: In the question computed property is working fine like, until user fill max characters in each fields only button is enabling.

Comment: Not understood. Do you want fullname to always be 10 characters long (maxfullname)? No more no less?

Comment: if i keep condition for maxfullname=10, then after entering 10 characters only button is enabling. But i need as maxlength should be 30 characters for fullname, and even if user enter lessthan 30 characters(either 10,5,6....etc) then also button has to enable.