# Issue with Changing button color after all fields are filled in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Had reference from [How to change button color after all fields are filled in vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593517/how-to-change-button-color-after-all-fields-are-filled-in-vuejs)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        user: {
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
      
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
       return !this.terms 
         || this.user.password === ''
         || this.user.confirmPassword === ''
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.register-button {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee1d24;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.selected {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
    
     <input
                  :type="passwordFieldType"
                  v-model="user.password"
                  
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  class="input-section-three-login"
                   value=""
                                 
                  placeholder="Enter new password"
                  :maxlength="maxpassword" 
                  autocomplete="off"

                />
       <input
                  :type="passwordFieldTypetwo"
                  v-model="user.confirmPassword"
                  id="confirmPassword"
                  name="confirmPassword"
                  class="input-section-three-login"
                 
                  placeholder="Confirm password"
                  :maxlength="maxconfirmpassword"
                  value="" autocomplete="off"
                  
                  :disabled="user.password.length < 8"
                />
    </label>
    
  </p>
   
  <input type="submit" value="Register"v-on:click="registerMe"
   :disabled="user.password && !$v.user.password.valid  ||    user.confirmPassword && !$v.user.confirmPassword.sameAsPassword " :class="(isDisabled) ? '' : 'selected'" @click="persist" />
</div>
```

Tried changing button color, after user enter all fields, but issue by default its taking selected css property

Had reference from [How to change button color after all fields are filled in vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593517/how-to-change-button-color-after-all-fields-are-filled-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data1: '',
    data2: ''
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      alert(this.data1 +' '+this.data2)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    empty() {
      return this.data1 === '' || this.data2 === '';
    },
    equal() {
      return this.data1 === this.data2;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.equal {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 2rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.no-equal {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="data1" type="text">
  <input v-model="data2" type="text">
  <button @click="click" :class="[equal ? 'equal' : 'no-equal']" :disabled="empty">Send</button>
</div>
```

You only need to evaluate one [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed) and biding [class in your elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) and vuejs will automatically render it.

Comment: In my case in the button i already have  :disabled="user.password && !$v.user.password.valid  ||
       user.confirmPassword && !$v.user.confirmPassword.sameAsPassword"

Comment: So how can i add :disabled="empty" in the button

Comment: Yeah, your code disabled the button, but not change the button color. My code does both things at the same time. I told you already, using a computed property

Comment: Thanks its working fine, But in the second input field if i enter single character button color is changing, So can we keep condition like if its match with 1st input field then only change button color

Comment: changing the validation to `this.data1 === this.data2` and adding other computed???

Comment: No only one computed. Tried replacing return this.data1 === '' || this.data2 === ''; with this.data1 === this.data2. But its not satisfying

Comment: Try again my code. I think this time work how you to need it. Although this was very simple. You should have just read and researched a little.